# Run-time error '1004': Method SaveAs of object _Workbook failed

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, save

I'm writing a program that saves a workbook to a specific folder based on some cell values in the workbook. Everything works as it should until I get to the ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs line, where I get a Run-time error 1004.

`Sub Tester()

```
Dim qNum, fldr As String
Dim custName As String
Dim myFileName As String
Dim completePath As String
Dim division As String

custName = Range("B12").Value
qNum = Range("B19").Value

If custName = "CNUL - Albian" Then
    custName = "CNRL"
    division = "Albian"
End If
If custName = "CNUL - Horizon" Then
    custName = "CNRL"
    division = "Horizon"
End If
If custName = "CNRL - Albian" Then
    custName = "CNRL"
    division = "Albian"
End If
If custName = "CNRL - Horizon" Then
    custName = "CNRL"
    division = "Horizon"
End If

If custName = "CNRL" Then
    fldr = GetMatchingPathCNRL(qNum, custName, division) '<< find the        matching folder
    If Len(fldr) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Found folder for customer=" & custName & _
                        ", Qnum=" & qNum & vbLf & fldr
            '...use this path

    Else
        MsgBox "No matching folder!", vbExclamation
    End If
Else
    fldr = GetMatchingPath(qNum, custName) '<< find the matching folder
    If Len(fldr) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Found folder for customer=" & custName & _
                    ", Qnum=" & qNum & vbLf & fldr
        '...use this path

    Else
        MsgBox "No matching folder!", vbExclamation
    End If
End If


myFileName = custName & " " & qNum & " " & "MTO Rev A"
completePath = fldr & "\" & myFileName

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=completePath
End Sub

Function GetMatchingPath(qNum, custName) As String
Const ROOT As String = "P:\MyCompany\" '<< adjust to suit
Dim f
f = Dir(ROOT & custName & "\*" & qNum & "*", vbDirectory)
GetMatchingPath = ROOT & custName & "\" & f
End Function


Function GetMatchingPathCNRL(qNum, custName, division) As String
Const ROOT As String = "P:\MyCompany\" '<< adjust to suit
Dim f
f = Dir(ROOT & custName & "\" & division & "\*" & qNum & "*", vbDirectory)
GetMatchingPathCNRL = ROOT & custName & "\" & f
End Function
```

`
The idea is that if the customer is CNRL there is an extra layer of folders to go through. The 4 'if' statements at the beginning are just to navigate a few different ways people may enter information into the spreadsheet.

I am always getting a 1004 error when it gets to the save file line, but the variables are all storing the correct names and folder paths. Any ideas?

Comment: What does `debug.print completePath` return to the immediate window?

Comment: @jeffreyweir - Found folder for customer=SYNCRUDE, Qnum=Q-188888
P:\MyCompany\SYNCRUDE\

Comment: That's not what I asked. Add `debug.print completePath` to your code before the SaveAs, and let us know what it returns.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `division` in the return path from `GetMatchingPathCNRL`:

```
f = Dir(ROOT & custName & "\" & division & "\*" & qNum & "*", vbDirectory)
GetMatchingPathCNRL = ROOT & custName & "\" & f
```

should be

```
GetMatchingPathCNRL = ROOT & custName & "\" & division & "\" & f
```

EDIT: I think it's preferable to centralize the "path" logic into one place, instead of having two different functions where you have to figure out which one to call...

```
Function GetMatchingPath(qNum, custName, division) As String
    Const ROOT As String = "P:\MyCompany\" '<< adjust to suit
    Dim fPath As String, f

    fPath = ROOT & custName & "\"
    If custName = "CNRL" Then fPath = fPath & division & "\"

    f = Dir(fPath & "*" & qNum & "*", vbDirectory)
    GetMatchingPath = IIf(f <> "", fPath & f, "")
End Function
```